# Is it possible to make a unique value in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm making a array class and want a value to be able to be returned by a higher order function. The idea is that its a instance constant or method returned value such that I can skip the value in a `map`.

In other languages making an array or some compound value, like `['skip']` will make it pointer equal such that I can then use the operator for pointer equal and it will not be equal to other arrays with the exact same content, but my problem is that `['skip'] === ['skip']` is true so even with `===` the two values are the same.

Here is an example of usage of my code where I accedentally have the same value as I used to skip:

```
namespace Test;
use Common\Domain\Collection;

$arr = new Collection();
$arr[] = 1;
$arr[] = 2;
$arr[] = 3;
$arr[] = 4;
echo count($arr); // prints 4
$arr2 = $arr->map(function ($v) { 
    return $v % 2 == 0 ? Collection::SKIP : ["skip"]; 
});
echo count($arr2); // prints 0, but should be 2
```

Is there a way to get a unique value or work around this somehow?
Here is code that implements `Collection`:

```php
namespace Common\Domain;;

class Collection implements \Iterator, \Countable, \ArrayAccess
{
    const SKIP = ["skip"];
    private $arr = [];

    public function map(callable $fn, bool $keepKeys = false) :Collection
    {
        $arr = new static();
        $nOrder = 0;
        foreach($this->arr as $key => $value) {
            $result = call_user_func($fn, $value, $key, $nOrder, $this);
            if($result !== self::SKIP) {
                if($keepKeys) {
                    $arr[$key] = $result;
                } else {
                    $arr[] = $result;
                }
            }
        }
        return $arr;
    }

    // implementation of interfaces \Iterator, \Countable, \ArrayAccess

    public function current()
    {
        return current($this->arr);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        next($this->arr);
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return key($this->arr);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return isset($this->arr[$this->key()]);
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        reset($this->arr);
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return count($this->arr);
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return array_key_exists($offset, $this->arr);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return $this->arr[$offset];
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        $this->arr[$offset] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset($this->arr[$offset]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Voting to close without commenting on the grounds that something is unclear? What is unclear exactly?

Comment: From Review Queue: voted to Leave Open.  While it doesn't display the best English that I've ever seen, 
 this question is sufficiently clear with sample input data, broken code, and an expected result.

Comment: I understand the problem, and unfortunately PHP is exceptionally weak when it comes to object oriented programming, but I am curious why you want to return `['skip']` for all values? Is that the real use case?

Comment: And also, your implementation of `map` looks more like a `filter` implementation. Which, if you were to use `filter`, would immediately solve your problem.

Comment: @fubar It was a test. My point is that my value needed to be something that other code could not by accident be returning. In perl `['skip'] == ['skip']` is false so I can make a unique value that way. Yes. You could easily implement `filter` with this `map`, but notice that I skip sometimes and other times change the value. The class answer seems very promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for Java-type enumerations, which doesn't exist in PHP. My best guess on your problem would be to use an object instead of a constant, that you would instantiate statically for a convenient use. Then, in the loop of your map function, you check the value with an `instanceof` instead of the basic equality operator, against the class you defined.

So, here :

```
class UniqueValue
{
    public static function get()
    {
        return new self();
    }
}
```

Then :

```
$arr2 = $arr->map(function ($v) { 
    return $v % 2 == 0 ? UniqueValue::get() : ["skip"]; 
});
```

And inside your collection :

```
public function map(callable $fn, bool $keepKeys = false) :Collection
    {
        $arr = new static();
        $nOrder = 0;
        foreach($this->arr as $key => $value) {
            $result = call_user_func($fn, $value, $key, $nOrder, $this);
            if($result ! instanceof UniqueValue) {
                if($keepKeys) {
                    $arr[$key] = $result;
                } else {
                    $arr[] = $result;
                }
            }
        }
        return $arr;
    }
```

This is the quickest approach I can think of. If your array contains data from "outside" I don't think it's possible in any way that it matches against a class check from your own code.

Comment: This can work!. I'll make it a singleton and users can get it with `Collection:getSkip()` instead of a constant. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by implementing another method for this. The method `delete` would map a function over the collection and remove any elements where the function returns false.

e.g.

```
class Collection
{
// ...
    public function delete($func)
    {
        $result = new static();
        foreach($this->arr as $item)
        {
            if($func($item) !== false) $result[] = $item;
        }
    }
}

// example

$arr = new Collection();
$arr[] = 1;
$arr[] = 2;
$arr[] = 3;
$arr[] = 4;
echo count($arr); // prints 4
$arr2 = $arr->delete(function ($v) { 
  return $v % 2 ? true : false;
});
var_dump($arr2); // prints [2, 4]
```

Comment: Not the answer I'm looking for.  Note that my `map` didn't leave the non skipped values as is.